# R variable not recognized (argument is of length zero)

Tags: r, seurat

I am having an issue with R recognizing a variable.

**Background**: I am using a tool called [DoubletFinder](https://github.com/chris-mcginnis-ucsf/DoubletFinder) *(an R package that predicts doublets in single-cell RNA sequencing data*. The RNA data is used to make a [Seurat](https://satijalab.org/seurat/) object and as part of the DoubletFinder process, there are some values that are calculated and stored therein within the `meta.data` slot. The name of the field holding the DoubletFinder data will start with `pANN` and is followed by a string of characters that will not be known in advance.

I need to automate this so I use grepl to search through the `meta.data` slot for fields containing the pANN values (line 183, e.g. "pANN_0.25_0.005_0"), assign it to a variable, and use it during the second `doubletFinder_v3` call (line 189, `reuse.pANN = pann_data`).

**Code**:

```
183    pann_data = colnames(seurat_object@meta.data)[grepl("pANN", colnames(seurat_object@meta.data))]
184    annotations <- seurat_object@meta.data$seurat_clusters
185    homotypic.prop <- modelHomotypic(annotations)
186    nExp_poi <- round(doublet_rate*nrow(seurat_object@meta.data))
187    nExp_poi.adj <- round(nExp_poi*(1-homotypic.prop))
188    seurat_object <- doubletFinder_v3(seurat_object, PCs = 1:components, pN = pN, pK = pk_value, nExp = nExp_poi, reuse.pANN = FALSE, sct = FALSE)
189    seurat_object <- doubletFinder_v3(seurat_object, PCs = 1:components, pN = pN, pK = pk_value, nExp = nExp_poi.adj, reuse.pANN = pann_data, sct = FALSE)
```

**Error**:

```
Error in if (reuse.pANN != FALSE) { : argument is of length zero
Calls: run_doubletfinder -> doubletFinder_v3
Execution halted
```

The `argument is of length zero` which makes me think this is not a DoubletFinder issue per se, the DoubletFinder command is not recognizing the variable. As proof, if I do the following, it works:

```
189    seurat_object <- doubletFinder_v3(seurat_object, PCs = 1:components, pN = pN, pK = pk_value, nExp = nExp_poi.adj, reuse.pANN = "pANN_0.25_0.005_0", sct = FALSE)
```

I have tried `seurat_object@meta.data[[pann_data]]` and `seurat_object@meta.data$pann_data` as well.

Does anyone have a work-around that would allow me to keep the process automated? Any advice/suggestions are warmly appreciated with many thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd bet that there is a small syntax error here. In my experience, this error means I've tried to execute a function on a object that doesn't exist or is empty. Run your code line by line and look at the result of each. I appreciate the information you've shared to describe your problme, but without a reproducible example (with data and full code to reproduce your problem), it's hard to give more specific advice.

Comment: @Skaqqs Yes of course, though I could not come up with a way to provide the data. I did find a work-around, I did not reuse the pANN values...For those using DF, you have the option of reusing the pANN values (`reuse.pANN = "pANN_0.25_0.005_0"`) or not (`reuse.pANN = FALSE`), I used the latter with success.

Comment: P.S. This will create two slots that contain doublet/singlet classifications. Be sure to look at both.